# About a Matrix equation $ P(LP)^\dagger = (LP)^\dagger$

Tags: matrix-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

**Have solved!**

According to *@obareey*'s comment, [the key to the proof](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#/Projectors) is trying to verify $P(LP)^\dagger$ is just the pseudoinverse of $LP$, using the existence and uniqueness of Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse. I am so pity that it's really a way I should find.

---

The following is the original question:

---

Let $ P\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}, L\in \mathbb{C}^{p\times n} $ and
$P$ is a projection matrix, i.e. $P^2=P,P^H=P$, then **why** such equation holds
$$
P(LP)^\dagger  =  (LP)^\dagger,
$$
where $\dagger$ represents Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse.

---

The problem comes from a paper I read recently, whose name is [*A Weighted Pseudoinverse, Generalized Singular Values, And Constrained Least Squares Problem*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01934412). **It lies the end of
the proof of Theorem2.1(Section2).** The author say "it is easily seen that equation", while I  couldn't understand the reason.

---

I have tried to focus on that P is a projection matrix and can be **unitary similar diagonalized** but I dosen't get the wanted result.

Comment: Please make the title more descriptive.

Comment: @mr_e_manm How about that now.

Comment: There is a sketch of the proof in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Projectors

Comment: @obareey Wow, Thank you very much. I get it! I'll modify the problem's body and leave the most important  thought of proof there.